# Trigger UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete when button inside tableview cell is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

[image]

This is my cell what I need to achieve is when I tap the icon on left side of my cell it trigger as if the user swipe the cell.

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell also I wired the icon(button). It look like this

```
- (IBAction)didPressMinusButton:(id)sender {

    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];

}
```

In my tableView I also have this

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //my code for deletion here
}
```

I would like to achieve when the user tap the icon in left side of my cell I should show the remove or delete. basically like swipe but in this case I just trigger it by tap.

Comment: what is your question i cant understand what you actually want ?

Comment: can you please more briefly your question?

Comment: If I tapped the icon in left side of my cell the minus with circled border I would like to show the remove or delete, as if i swipe the cell

Comment: its also you can perform its with swap the tableviewcell try it

Comment: yes I achieve the swipe part but it would be nice if I could show the delete button when I tapped those icon

Comment: you can achieve this by adding custom 'Remove' button

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ  Hi , ohh I get what you're saying , I could do that but right now I'm looking for quick fix cos that way could took quite time. thanks for suggestion that would be my last resort

Answer (score 0):

You mean that when user tap on minus icon on left then the remove functionality should work instead of swipe.Right ?

If yes, then just remove this code or make comments for this

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //my code for deletion here
}
```

Comment: hi! , not much, when I tapped the icon the remove or delete button should show. not actually trigger the delete

Comment: Ok you mean that when you tap on minus icon then remove would appear same as the swipe does. And not when the user swipes the cell. Right ?

Comment: the swipe still there, what the tap on button does is just mimic to what swipe does

Comment: In that case, please prefer this link : [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278091/how-cell-swipe-on-clicking-a-button)