# tableview display more option on `didSelect` event

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

How to display the uitableview's swipe option on `didselectRow:`

want to display swipe option like below.[image]

exmaple show in fig, this should implement in didselect row. How can achive this help me. Thanks advance.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: tableView.setEditing(!tableView.isEditing, animated: true) use this code to edit the cell. but want to didselect the option

Comment: ru there help me

Comment: if you want to tap the cell you want to open the swipe on tail

Comment: yes... it like didselect the uitableview.

Comment: hello ru there?

Comment: Please paste your code. If you're asking people to implement this, you're missing the point here. I'll give you a hint to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27389620/8558606) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewrowaction).

Answer (score 0):

First , you should sure that:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // the cells you would like the actions to appear needs to be editable
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // you need to implement this method too or you can't swipe to display the actions
}
```

and second you will implementate in this delegate method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "More") { action, index in
        println("more button tapped")
    }
    more.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Favorite") { action, index in
        println("favorite button tapped")
    }
    favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
        println("share button tapped")
    }
    share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [share, favorite, more]
}
```

the finall view like that:
[image]
hope this is helpful for you.