# How to show user a preview of the swipe actions for a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

I have a UITableViewController that allows users to swipe left to Remove/Delete/Flag Actions. While this is a common iOS feature, we want to make sure the user knows it's there by doing a quick animation of it sliding open the first time it's viewed.

Is there a way to programmatically slide a UITableViewCell to reveal the actions?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add UILabel to the cell you'd like to animate. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766243/uitableview-invoke-swipe-actions-programmatically) is some source code.